# Arduino WebSockets Client with PHP WebSockets server

Tags: php, websocket, arduino

I'm developing a system that requires Websockets establishment between the client and the server. I followed this example:

https://github.com/krohling/ArduinoWebsocketClient

The echo server is not replying back. This is my code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WebSocketClient.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
char server[] = "echo.websocket.org";
WebSocketClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  client.connect(server);
  client.setDataArrivedDelegate(dataArrived);
  client.send("Hello World!");
}

void loop() {
  client.monitor();
}

void dataArrived(WebSocketClient client, String data) {
  Serial.println("Data Arrived: " + data);
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: What has this to do with PHP?

Comment: the websocket server is PHP based

Comment: Plesae describe what you have tried and where exactly it goes wrong.

Comment: Basically I tried the code above, it compiled successfully, but there is no reply from the echo server. I tried creating a simple application (web app) that talks to this echo server, and it worked. So i guess the problem is with the library. 
I want to have websockets working on arduino. I don't care if I change the library. Do you know any other libraries tested on Arduino Mega 2560 with ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Ethernet shield you are using, you should replace `#include <Ethernet.h>` by `#include <Ethernet2.h>`.

[Ethernet](http://www.arduino.org/products/shields/arduino-ethernet-shield)

[Ethernet2](http://www.arduino.org/products/shields/arduino-ethernet-shield-2)

The Ethernet2 library is only on the arduino IDE from arduino.org and not from arduino.cc

Comment: After seeing the link related to Ethernet2, I guess I need this shield to connect to the Internet. Ethernet is only used for private LANs. Am i right?

Comment: @OthmanMohammad It depends on what you plan to do, but of course if you want to echo an internet server, you will need to connect the board to the internet. As you are client side no specific box configuration is needed, just plug the cable to Arduino and to the box.